# ngx-translate .instant() doesn't load is not instant

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, ngx-translate

I translate data that I get locally, they are not async data.

My native text comes from an enum imported in my file `V2VehiculeOutput.StatusEnum`

But I am forced to reload the page if I want to see the translation.

I tried to load translations, with the code bellow, from the ngOnInit and the constructor but it doesn't change anything.

```
    Object.keys(V2VehiculeOutput.StatusEnum).forEach(s => {
      console.log(this.translate.instant('FILTERS.VEHICULE.STATUS.' + V2VehiculeOutput.StatusEnum[s]));
      });
    });
```

I read that issue https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/517 but my data is not even async ... So why translate.instant is not loading my data directly ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Could you please share how you are loading the translation, by`HttpTranslateLoader` or manually by `addLangs` method? Where you init the defaultLang, and `use` it?

Answer (score 0):

This post https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-ngx-translate helped me.

It seems to work normally now using this exemple.

```
this.translate.get(['login.username', 'login.password'])
      .subscribe(translations => {
        this.usernameLabel = translations['login.username'];
        this.passwordLabel = translations['login.password'];
});
```

The bug was not on each load so I will keep an eye on that but it feels good for the moment.